# CPT Meta Searching

Tags: custom-post-types, search, meta-query

I'm developing a WP plugin which uses custom post types and meta data. What I'm trying to achieve is having the meta data searchable. Here is some code that I found which searches the meta data fine, however I can't get it to display the search string on the CPT page.

[image: CPT Search Error]

```
add_filter( "pre_get_posts", "custom_search_query");
function custom_search_query( $query ) {
    $custom_fields = array(
        "pctracker_company",
        "pctracker_customer",
        "pctracker_phone1",
        "pctracker_phone2",
        "pctracker_mobile",
        "pctracker_email"

    );
    $searchterm = $query->query_vars['s'];
    $query->query_vars['s'] = "";
    if ($searchterm != "") {
        $meta_query = array('relation' => 'OR');
        foreach($custom_fields as $cf){
            array_push($meta_query, array(
                'key' => $cf,
                'value' => $searchterm,
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            ));
        }
        $query->set("meta_query", $meta_query);
    };
}
```

I know that in the code its unsetting 'S', however if you don't unset it, it does not display any results.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks very much,
Jason

EDIT:

I've just been having a play around and I've got this working!

```
function my_search_results($query){
    if(isset($_GET['s'])){
        if($_GET['post_type'] == "pctracker_customers") {
            $mySearch = $_REQUEST['s'];
            $query = 'select * from wp_posts,wp_postmeta WHERE wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id AND wp_postmeta.meta_key = "pctracker_phone1" AND wp_postmeta.meta_value LIKE "%'.$mySearch.'%" AND(wp_posts.post_status = "publish")';
        }
    }
    return $query;
}
add_filter( 'posts_request', 'my_search_results');
```

EDIT 2:
I've got multiple meta fields I need to search, pctracker_phone1 and pctracker_phone2 are just a couple. I've edited the SQL code so it searches for both. However the SQL code is going to be massive once all of the other metafields are added. Do you know how I could simplifier this:

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM '. $wpdb->prefix .'posts,'. $wpdb->prefix .'postmeta WHERE '. $wpdb->prefix .'posts.ID = '. $wpdb->prefix .'postmeta.post_id AND '. $wpdb->prefix .'postmeta.meta_key = "pctracker_phone1" AND '. $wpdb->prefix .'postmeta.meta_value LIKE "%'.$mySearch.'%" OR '. $wpdb->prefix .'posts.ID = '. $wpdb->prefix .'postmeta.post_id AND '. $wpdb->prefix .'postmeta.meta_key = "pctracker_phone2" AND '. $wpdb->prefix .'postmeta.meta_value LIKE "%'.$mySearch.'%" AND('. $wpdb->prefix .'posts.post_status = "publish") ORDER BY '. $wpdb->prefix .'posts.post_date DESC';
```

Comment: Is the question for front-end or admin search? Also: Is the search running on the default search input field or is there something custom like a drop down that gets populated to process a precise and more fine grained search?

Comment: Its in the admin side using the default search input.

Comment: I've just done an update!

Comment: Do a `esc_attr()` or `filter_var()` on `$_REQUEST['s']` to avoid getting hacked. Also post it as an answer instead of an update :)

Comment: Just added that thanks, just one last question you might be able to help me with...

Comment: Jason... again: Not as an edit - as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The code you found modifies the main query on `pre_get_posts` and unsets the search terms so `WP_Query` doesn't run a real search query. What you want is

```
// Filter the search SQL that is used in the WHERE clause of WP_Query.
apply_filters_ref_array( 'posts_search', array( $search, &$this ) );
```

which runs [previously in `WP_Query::get_posts()`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/1ff0aebf20dec2a7a5636127e27c9df58a6a084d/wp-includes/query.php#L2478). This later on adds to the `WHERE` clause:

```
$where .= $search . $whichauthor . $whichmimetype;
```

where the author part is:

```
" AND ($wpdb->posts.post_author = " . absint($q['author']) . ')';
```

and the MIME-Type part uses [`wp_post_mime_type_where()`](http://queryposts.com/function/wp_post_mime_type_where/) and is

```
$whichmimetype = wp_post_mime_type_where( $q['post_mime_type'], $wpdb->posts );
```

If the `s` query var is **set**, you can use `orderby` as well and modify it from a filter:

```
$search_orderby = apply_filters( 'posts_search_orderby', $search_orderby, $this );
```

The result of this will be the **first** `ORDER BY` SQL argument followed by whatever was specified as default `ORDER BY` argument. If there was no default, it will fall back to the search argument.

```
$orderby = $orderby ? $search_orderby . ', ' . $orderby : $search_orderby;
```

Of course you still can then use the `posts_clauses` and the related filters. You do an early hands on inspection of your results to check if you managed to get a working query by hooking in on

```
do_action( 'posts_selection', $where . $groupby . $orderby . $limits . $join );
```

This will give you the complete final SQL string.

Keep in mind that other plugins might as well jump in on the `pre_get_posts`, `posts_request` or `posts_clauses`, `posts_*` filters and that you won't really be able to work around such conflicts in a generic way.

Comment: Thanks very much for the reply. Sounds like its very much over my head! :-(

Comment: @Jason You're welcome :) Anyway, as you can read in the title, this sites audience is developers (and people trying to learn developing). Start with reading about filters, hooks and actions (callbacks) and try the different mentioned filters above. Update your question with what you've tried, where you failed, etc. The first step to evolve is to push yourself hard enough and try things that are over your head :)

Answer (score -1):

I've got multiple meta fields I need to search, pctracker_phone1 and pctracker_phone2 are just a couple. I've edited the SQL code so it searches for both. However the SQL code is going to be massive once all of the other metafields are added. Do you know how I could simplifier this:

```
function my_search_results($query){
if(isset($_GET['s'])){
    if($_GET['post_type'] == "pctracker_customers") {
        $mySearch = $_REQUEST['s'];
        $query = 'SELECT * FROM '. $wpdb->prefix .'posts,'. $wpdb->prefix .'postmeta WHERE '. $wpdb->prefix .'posts.ID = '. $wpdb->prefix .'postmeta.post_id AND '. $wpdb->prefix .'postmeta.meta_key = "pctracker_phone1" AND '. $wpdb->prefix .'postmeta.meta_value LIKE "%'.$mySearch.'%" OR '. $wpdb->prefix .'posts.ID = '. $wpdb->prefix .'postmeta.post_id AND '. $wpdb->prefix .'postmeta.meta_key = "pctracker_phone2" AND '. $wpdb->prefix .'postmeta.meta_value LIKE "%'.$mySearch.'%" AND('. $wpdb->prefix .'posts.post_status = "publish") ORDER BY '. $wpdb->prefix .'posts.post_date DESC'; 
    }
}
return $query;
}
add_filter( 'posts_request', 'my_search_results');
```

Comment: Please update/edit your question with that info. Don´t  add new answers to ask additional questions.